# Reversed cursor for loop plsql

Tags: plsql

Is there a way to iterate a cursor in a descending order using plsql?

I tried this:

```
FOR item IN REVERSE items 
LOOP  
-- do stuff
END LOOP;
```

but it seems to ignore the reverse key word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your `items` consist of?

Comment: To be more specific, that simple select is on an xml file mapped to a table. The requirement is to traverse from the last xml tag to the first one, so there is no particular column to order by.

Comment: Do you mean that you have one row that contains the complete XML file, or one row per row in the XML file?

Comment: Each row maps to a tag in the xml file

Answer (score 6):

It is the SQL clause that determines the order in which the data is traversed, so just apply an appropriate ORDER BY in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
cursor c1 is Select * FROM table_1
where (something)
order by (id..whatever you want) DESC; --decrement
v_variable.table%rowtype;
BEGIN
open c1;

fetch c1 into variable; -- will fetch  first row...but it will be DESC

close c1;

END;
```

something like that...
 OR

```
FOR i1 IN c1
LOOP
i1.id...
something...
END LOOP;
```

OR

```
FOR i2 IN (Select * FROM table_1
    where (something)
    order by (id..whatever you want) DESC) 
LOOP
--something
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any column to order by, try using order by rownum